# how to get rid of empty elements

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an array thats generated dynamically and it has some empty elements. How do I get rid of empty elements from an array?

array
  0 => string '' (length=0)
  1 => string 'x%6wm' (length=5)
  2 => string 'x%6wmvf' (length=7)
  3 => string 'x%645' (length=5)
  4 => string '' (length=0)

And I want it to become like

array
  0 => string 'x%6wm' (length=5)
  1 => string 'x%6wmvf' (length=7)
  2 => string 'x%645' (length=5)
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the functions [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter) and [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values) to accomplish your goal.

`$cleanArray = array_values(array_filter($array));`

Comment: Is the array_values call necessary if you don't have any associative keys?

Comment: If you want to keep your array keys intact you should leave out `array_values`. However, if you want to have your array keys reset and without gaps you need to add this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop throuh it and check each element of the array if empty or not and if it's empty you can delete that element.

Comment: Inefficient.  Always use PHP built in functions when available -- theyre usually just wrappers to C functions, and as such, are super quick.  Looping through manually would take forever.

Answer (score 0):

Per above the array filter and values would work very well for this.

`$array = array("", "Hello", "", "World", "");`

$info = array_values(array_filter($array));

print_r($info);